# Is it possible to open a full screen map in battlefield 4 during play (while alive)?

Tags: battlefield-4

**Is it possible to open a full screen map in battlefield 4 during play (while alive)?**

In the bottom left of the screen I see a mini map and looking around I can see the objectives.  Can i change the mini map zoom levels or even better expand the map to full screen temporarily so I can plan my next action?

If so, how? (I play on PS4)

Comment: you can see the entire map if you go to the menu(ESC on PC, probably START on PS4). On PC you can also use <kbd>M</kbd> to expand it, but I don't know how to do it on a PS4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hold **Options and press R1** you should see a full map.

Comment: +1 Not sure why this is down voted, it is correct for PS4.

Answer (score 2):

Its true on the xbox as well, just start and Rb